# windows.h в linux

Tags: c++, linux

При работе с bmp в windows использую библиотеку windows.h, откуда мне собственно нужны только :

```
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bmfh;
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bmih;
    RGBTRIPLE RGBColor;
```

Как получить данные вещи в linux, а также какие типы данных использовать вместо виндовсовских, например BYTE

Comment: А для чего конкретно вы используете `windows.h` в проекте? Для графики или для чего? Просто боюсь, что на linux будут проблемы...

Comment: @Wolkodav для чтения заголовка bmp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Например, можно использовать libgd https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GD_Graphics_Library или ImageMagick https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageMagick

Если нужны только

```
 BITMAPFILEHEADER bmfh;
 BITMAPINFOHEADER bmih;
 RGBTRIPLE RGBColor;
```

Можно просто скопировать эти структуры из виндоус и адаптировать под линукс. Формат BMP не сложный, с ним можно разобраться...

Comment: Значит придется делать собственный windows.h с блекджеком и пингвинами, и будет он представлять из себя огрызок, но рабочий огрызок.

Comment: Можно сторонее использовать например [это](http://easybmp.sourceforge.net/). Можно почитать спецификацию `BMP` и самому накорябать.

Comment: Вот, например, структура typedef struct tagBITMAPFILEHEADER {
        WORD    bfType;
        DWORD   bfSize;
        WORD    bfReserved1;
        WORD    bfReserved2;
        DWORD   bfOffBits;
} BITMAPFILEHEADER; остало её заполнить из BMP-файла

Answer (score 4):

```
typedef int LONG;
typedef unsigned char BYTE;
typedef uint32_t DWORD;
typedef unsigned short WORD;

// __attribute__((packed)) on non-Intel arch may cause some unexpected error, plz be informed.

typedef struct tagBITMAPFILEHEADER
{
    WORD    bfType; // 2  /* Magic identifier */
    DWORD   bfSize; // 4  /* File size in bytes */
    WORD    bfReserved1; // 2
    WORD    bfReserved2; // 2
    DWORD   bfOffBits; // 4 /* Offset to image data, bytes */ 
} __attribute__((packed)) BITMAPFILEHEADER;

typedef struct tagBITMAPINFOHEADER
{
    DWORD    biSize; // 4 /* Header size in bytes */
    LONG     biWidth; // 4 /* Width of image */
    LONG     biHeight; // 4 /* Height of image */
    WORD     biPlanes; // 2 /* Number of colour planes */
    WORD     biBitCount; // 2 /* Bits per pixel */
    DWORD    biCompress; // 4 /* Compression type */
    DWORD    biSizeImage; // 4 /* Image size in bytes */
    LONG     biXPelsPerMeter; // 4
    LONG     biYPelsPerMeter; // 4 /* Pixels per meter */
    DWORD    biClrUsed; // 4 /* Number of colours */ 
    DWORD    biClrImportant; // 4 /* Important colours */ 
} __attribute__((packed)) BITMAPINFOHEADER;

/*
typedef struct tagRGBQUAD
{
    unsigned char    rgbBlue;   
    unsigned char    rgbGreen;
    unsigned char    rgbRed;  
    unsigned char    rgbReserved;
} RGBQUAD;
* for biBitCount is 16/24/32, it may be useless
*/

typedef struct tagRGBTRIPLE {
        BYTE    rgbtBlue;
        BYTE    rgbtGreen;
        BYTE    rgbtRed;
} RGBTRIPLE;

typedef struct
{
        BYTE    b;
        BYTE    g;
        BYTE    r;
} RGB_data; // RGB TYPE, plz also make sure the order
```

Comment: @Abyx, согласен, здесь нужны типы с гарантированным размером. Но нужен ли здесь префикс `std::`?